# Need clarification on the extend function for list in python. Please check the code below

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
    >>> a = [1,2,3]
    >>> b = [1,2]
    >>> a.append(b)
    >>> a
    [1, 2, 3, [1, 2]]
    >>> b
    [1, 2]
    >>> b.extend(a)
    >>> b
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, [...]]
    >>> b[5]
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

What is the `[...]` here? This is confusing me. What's wrong with my approach?
Can someone clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a circular reference. `a` contains the same list `b` was referencing. By extending `b` with `a`, `b` now contains a reference to itself.

Python displays such a reference by using `...` rather than go into an infinite loop. Printing `b[5]` is printing the same object again, so the output naturally is the same again.